# Is this possible through javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am currently working on asp.net project. I use oodle web service. Oodle provides result via URL. I use [Link](http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle&format=json) to get data from the URL.

From code behind I use following code to fetch the resultant string :

```
string url = 
    @"http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?
      key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle&format=json";
var jsonString = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

Now , My problem is I use button click event to run that code. But is this through `JavaScript` ? Because If I use `Javascript` it will be easier to access my resultant data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this API returns JSONP which means that you could consume it directly from javascript. For example if you use jQuery you could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle&format=json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonOodleApi',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.current.region.id);
    }
});
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADjq7/).

---

And if you don't use jQuery you could simply define a callback:

```
var jsonOodleApi = function(result) {
    alert(result.current.region.id);
};
```

and then include a `<script>` pointing to this url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle&format=json"></script>
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vQfQX/).

Obviously you could inject this script tag dynamically into the DOM whenever you want to invoke the API call.

Comment: This is limited for oodle ! If you try to change src=`https://graph.facebook.com/100003596013776/friends/?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAEvWtwZBsyq7RVCEUssCnolhYKUQpXPLkoxvZASmknwHovauVAV3ZCeadOE4rhqD4Ch6wGCZAOYMZA4B6xk5PAWmwZAcZC6zlVPL36TMNJb` it will no work ! why so ?

Comment: @NoOne, I am not familiar with Facebook. If this doesn't work it's probably because it doesn't support JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Ajax requests to the page through Javascrypt.

[here's a tutorial on that](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

If you are using some JavaScript frameworks, like JQuery, those requests would be easier to make, as the AJAX requests are kinda not cross-browser compatible.

[the JQuery version](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Actualy my point is it should not go in code behind. Because I want to manage this with java script because jsonstring is easy to access via javascript !

Comment: Jquery is the Javascrypt framework, which is written in javascrypt, so it's will not go into code behind.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an AJAX request. It it certainly possibly to do without libraries, but due to crossbrowser issues I would recommend using a library. With jQuery for example it could look like this (in a document ready part of script):

```
$("#idOfButton").click(function() {
  $.get('string url= @"http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle&format=json', function(jsonString) {
    alert('Data is now in variable jsonString!');
  });
});
```